# Mongo Aggregation With Projection

Tags: c#, mongodb

Given the following document

```
{
 "Id": "MyNormalObjectId",
 "CompanyId" : 1234,
 "User" : 
    {
         "UserId":4567,
         "FirstName":"Tester",
         "Lastname":"McCtesterson"
    }
}
```

How do I write my aggregate query to return a list of all unique users in a given company (including first and last name)?

```
FilterDefinitionBuilder<MyDoc> builder = Builders<MyDoc>.Filter;
var filter = builder .Eq(t => t.CompanyId, companyId);


var aggregate = _col.Aggregate();

aggregate.Match(filter).GroupBy(t=>t.User.UserId, ?????? )
```

Desired result would be a HashSet of UserMetadata. I've seen a lot of people go straight to BSon for what they need and I can if I HAVE to. Strongly typed is always better.

Comment: Unwind the `User` array before grouping.

Comment: sorry if it wasn't clear. the example is watered down for clarity to the point that maybe it isn't clear. the users are not in an array. one to one with each document.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `$addToSet` operator inside the `$group` pipeline stage
to get the desired output.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "CompanyId": 1234  // Find Conditions go here
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$CompanyId",
      "Users": {
        "$addToSet": "$User",
      },
    },
  },
])
```

Comment: what is the C# version of this?

Comment: This is in Mongo Shell, just convert it into C#